# Where are the screensaver configuration files (.saver) for the screensavers that are offered in "Desktop & Screen Saver" in Settings on El Capitan?

Tags: macos, login, screensaver, login-screen

I've already looked in 2 places.

I looked in my user folder: `/Users/MYUSERNAME/Library/Screen Savers` - which was empty.

(where MYUSERNAME is my user name)

I also looked in `/Library/Screen Savers/Default Collections` and found *images, but not the actual Screensaver configuration file itself (a .saver file, I believe):*
1-National Geographic   2-Aerial        3-Cosmos        4-Nature Patterns

- But this folder only has the photos and not the Screensaver files themselves (.saver I think).

I'm particularly interested in using the Classic screen saver for the *general* login screen (i.e. the initial overall general start up screen where the user(s) are displayed when left unattended, *not* for a particular user). Once I know where this is located, I will set it to run at the login screen (for when the machine is left unattended). I believe I can set it with this guide: http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/07/set-screen-saver-login-window-mac-os-x/
(but I first of all need to know where to find the .saver file, hence my question)

Comment: It quite clearly says they're in `/System/Library/Screen Savers/`Why don't you look in there?

Comment: There are three possible locations: `/Macintosh HD/System/Library/ScreenSavers`, `/Macintosh HD/Library/ScreenSavers`, and  `/Macintosh HD/Users/[your_username]/Library/ScreenSavers`.

Comment: I'll do a search on terminal, with `sudo find /* | grep *.saver`. I'll get back to you on this in a minute. UPDATE: Forgot I don't have admin access on the computer I'm using right now, can't search all directories. Someone else can do this, though. I can look this up when I get home.

Comment: @IconDaemon & FlareCat... The main reason I quite tersely pointed out where they actually **are** is because a) only user-additions would be anywhere else & b) they're not all called .saver

Comment: Tetsujin - I have looked in /System/Library/Screen Savers/  - not all the Screen Savers available in Settings are in there, but these ones are: Arabesque.qtz Flurry.saver Shell.saver iTunes Artwork.saver FloatingMessage.saver Random.saver Word of the Day.qtz